# VB To Copy Excel Sparklines

Tags: excel, vba, blueprism

I am using a Blueprism Process to run a VB Script. It copies a range of excel values and pastes as source formatting. When it runs it does not paste sparklines correctly.

Code:

```
Dim wb, excel, range As Object

Try

wb = GetWorkbook(Handle, Workbook)
excel = wb.Application

range = excel.Selection
range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=-4163, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)
range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=-4122, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)

Success = True

Catch e As Exception
Success = False
Message = e.Message
Finally
wb = Nothing
range = Nothing
End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you make 2 paste special. But Firstly you paste only values, later only format:

**xlPasteValues**   **-4163**   Values are pasted.
**xlPasteFormats**  **-4122**   Copied source format is pasted.

And you could do this in one line:

**xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats**   **12**  Values and Number formats are pasted.

But if you want to paste as source use this one:

**xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme**  **13**  Everything will be pasted using the source theme.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype

Comment: How do I add this into my code? I want to paste as values but keep all the source formatting. My code works but drops out the sparklines.

Comment: @Eoin2211 try range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False) sry for late response, did not saw your comment.

Comment: no problem. Blueprism produced the following error Page: Paste As Values And Surce Formatting
Stage: Paste Values And Source Formatting
Type: Error
Action: Validate
Description: Compiler error at line 9: 'xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Repairable: No

Comment: @Eoin2211 try then use number 13. Cause xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme = 13. Let us know

Comment: thanks. Could you amalgamate that into my code as I may be making errors in my understanding.

Comment: @Eoin2211 range = excel.Selection
range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=13, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)